Not able to connect flink to kafka
Getting below error
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient

while connecting flink to kafka
I am using flink 1.17 and using

flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.2.jar
kafka-clients-0.10.2.2.jar
flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.2.jar

additional jars. Please help if I am missing something.
Tried different versions of Jars but nothing seems to work. Also I am using dataproc cluster for the same.

Did you try adding flink-connector-kafka dependency?
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.2</version>
</dependency>

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#dependency
